# Fixed background doesn't get updated on Android

Tags: html, css, background

I've found a similar question here but with no answer, yet I can't find an alternative as a solution.

I have the following code and it works perfectly on Mac and Windows, however I can't figure out why on Android (either Chrome or Firefox) the background does not get updated when the user is scrolling down, it produces the space of about 1/5 of the screen at the bottom while scrolling down.
The background image gets updated after you release the touch.

```
html{
  background-image:url(example.jpg);
  background-position:fixed;
  background-size:100% 100%;
}
```

Comment: Use the `body` Element instead.

Comment: @PHPglue I've tried that, no luck!

Comment: Try it on the first Element inside the `body`. Wrap everything.

Comment: @PHPglue I would really prefer to keep it as html or body, if there's no solution to it then I will try a wrapper.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Specify a height for your html and body, i.e.

```
html     {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
```

And

```
body    {
    height: 100%;
    min-height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}
```

And add a div that will wrap everything inside body, i.e.

```
<body>
    <div id="wrapmeup">
      ....your content....
    </div>
</body>
```

And finally add this to your css:

```
#wrapmeup {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    background-image: url(image/background.jpg);
    background-attachment: fixed;
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

Comment: Mobile devices's small screen-size leads to a smaller viewport so a wrapper is required

Comment: #wrapmeup also needs a value to position. I added `position:fixed` with the rest of the code, the result is exactly the same as using html/body.

Comment: You don't need to add position: fixed as `background-size: cover;` expands the image to cover the whole site completely.

Comment: Right, but the image doesn't display without adding a position.

Comment: Add this `background-attachment: fixed;` to the wrapper div and also add this to your css: html{width:100%; height:100%;}

Comment: Thank you, just tried it and it doesn't make a difference.

Comment: However, I've found the solution with your help.

Comment: Glad I could helped Nima :)

Comment: It has some downside but in my case it fixes the issue! `#wrapmeup {
    height: 120%;
    width: 100%;
    background-image: url(../img/bg/material/06.jpg);
    position: fixed;
    top: -10%;bottom: -10%;left: 0;right: 0;
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}`

Comment: height: 120%; lol nice :D More of a hack rather than a fix but it solved the issue though lol

Comment: Oh and just out of curiosity, why are you using background-attachment: fixed; instead of position: fixed; btw??

Comment: Yes a hack! Because it's a known bug and there seems to be no solution to it as I've been searching over here and on Google. So this hack can do the solution in my case. I used `positon:fixed` because it gives a definition to the div just like float:left and display:block so the div is defnied. Another reason is to have the div fixed on the page...